# Assign Labels According to Percentiles

Tags: r, percentile

Trying to solve Python problems into R code.

I would like to assign titles according to the grade in a new column.

For example:

- 'A' for values greater than or equal to the 99.92<sup>th</sup> percentile
- 'B' for values less than the 99.92<sup>th</sup> percentile but greater than or equal to the 84.92<sup>th</sup> percentile
- 'C' for values less than the 84.92<sup>th</sup> percentile but greater than or equal to the 59.92<sup>th</sup> percentile
- 'D' for values less than the 59.92<sup>th</sup> percentile but greater than or equal to the 29.92<sup>th</sup> percentile
- 'E' for values less than the 29.92<sup>th</sup> percentile but greater than or equal to the 15.92<sup>th</sup> percentile
- 'F' for all values less than the 15.92<sup>th</sup> percentile.

There is this column:

```
Grades
2.3
3
2
3.3
3.5
3.6
3.2
2.1
2.3
3.7
3.3
3.1
4.4
4.3
1.4
4.5
3.5
```

This is what i tried.

```
 quantile(w$Grades, c(.91, .75))
```

and so on.. but after the first i think there should be a subtraction at the next percentiles since the lower percentiles shouldn't include the higher.This is how i get it.

Comment: You want to use `cut` with `quantile`

Comment: I think is tricky how to use the '_next _ _so_ percent' part how to deal with the previous part

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Can you describe how to use the `cut` and `breaks` in `quantile` for the task?As i said the _next_ percent part is the problem.How to make it and not have issues with the previous percentiles.

Comment: `w$letter_grade <- cut(w$Grades, breaks = quantile(w$Grades, probs = cumsum(c(0, 0.9, 15, 25, 30, 13, 16.1)) / 100), labels = LETTERS[1:6], include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: @alistaire Perhaps grades will be just opposite.

Comment: I had worked out: `df$letter <- cut(df$Grades, breaks = quantile(df$Grades, probs = c(0, 0.161, 0.291, 0.591, 0.841, .991, 1)),
    labels = c("F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"), include.lowest = TRUE)` will work

Comment: Ah, yeah, probably `LETTERS[6:1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Overview

I stored the quantiles as a vector, and used those values in [`sapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.99.14.9/topics/Sapply) to label values in `Grade` that fell between the quantiles.

## Reproducible Example

I used the [`read.table()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) function to import your example data into [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Afterwards, I stored the sample quantiles from the output of [`quantiles()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) in `interested.quantiles`. Each percentile - one for each [0,1] value in the `probs` argument - [represents the value below which a given percentage of observations in `df$Grade` fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).

Finally, I input `df$Grade` as the X input in `sapply()`, and applied an anonymous function for each value in X. The function inspects which of the six groups each value of X falls into through a series of [`if()` and `else if()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html) functions. Since the values in `interested.quantiles` were created in descending order of percentiles, the if statements check if the X value is greater than or equal to the 99.92<sup>th</sup>. If true, it returns 'A'; if false, it continues checking where X falls in the remaining percentiles.

```
# create data
df <-
  read.table( text = "Grades
2.3
3
2
3.3
3.5
3.6
3.2
2.1
2.3
3.7
3.3
3.1
4.4
4.3
1.4
4.5
3.5"
              , header = TRUE
  )


# create quantiles based on 
# interested probabilities
# from df$Grade
interested.quantiles <-
  quantile( x = df$Grades
            , probs = c( 0.9992, 0.8492, 0.5992, 0.2992, 0.1592 )
  )

# view vector
interested.quantiles
#  99.92%  84.92%  59.92%  29.92%  15.92% 
# 4.49872 4.05232 3.41744 2.85104 2.20944 

# Assign labels based on each
# Grade's value
df$Label <-
  sapply( X = df$Grades
          , FUN = function( i )
            if( i >= interested.quantiles[ 1 ] ){

              return( "A" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 1 ] &&
                        i >= interested.quantiles[ 2 ] ){

              return( "B" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 2 ] &&
                        i >= interested.quantiles[ 3 ] ){

              return( "C" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 3 ] &&
                        i >= interested.quantiles[ 4 ] ){

              return( "D" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 4 ] &&
                        i >= interested.quantiles[ 5 ] ){

              return( "E" )

            } else{

              return( "F")
            }

  )

# view results
df
#    Grades Label
# 1     2.3     E
# 2     3.0     D
# 3     2.0     F
# 4     3.3     D
# 5     3.5     C
# 6     3.6     C
# 7     3.2     D
# 8     2.1     F
# 9     2.3     E
# 10    3.7     C
# 11    3.3     D
# 12    3.1     D
# 13    4.4     B
# 14    4.3     B
# 15    1.4     F
# 16    4.5     A
# 17    3.5     C

# end of script #
```

## Additional Data Set

A [link to a CSV file of their actual data set](http://www.mediafire.com/file/3n6c5e6q2wdemmn/stackoverfl) was given in the comments. Here is the same logic applied to the new data set.

*Note: there are no 'F' values in `df$Label`. This is not a mistake; rather, it is a great lesson in understanding data. 20.77% of the values in `df$rfm_score` are the value 1.8. The smallest percentile of interest is 15.92% - which to no surprise - is associated with the value 1.8. When the anonymous function in `sapply()` searches for values less than 1.8, it comes up empty. Therefore, no `df$rm_score` could ever possess the label 'F' because no value in that vector is smaller than 1.8.*

```
# create data
df <- 
  read.csv( file = "http://download1519.mediafire.com/cjsv2c7r112g/3n6c5e6q2wdemmn/stackoverfl"
            , header = TRUE
            , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# view data
str( df )
# 'data.frame': 157711 obs. of  13 variables:
# $ X              : int  9 128 193 227 265 291 311 419 422 434 ...
# $ Member_id      : int  100010 100259 100378 100443 100535 100588 100619 100811 100816 100833 ...
# $ Invoice_id     : int  1728650 1613593 1617369 1597363 1733884 1598267 1603355 1619466 1688050 1645517 ...
# $ Grandtotal     : num  9.9 2.5 25.8 32.1 10.3 ...
# $ InvoiceDate    : chr  "2017-03-18" "2017-01-10" "2017-01-12" "2017-01-04" ...
# $ recency        : int  65 44 70 1 11 40 58 15 81 22 ...
# $ freq           : int  7 10 7 11 9 7 13 10 9 9 ...
# $ monetary_v     : num  95.3 114.5 103.6 144.4 113.3 ...
# $ rank_recency   : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
# $ rank_freq      : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
# $ rank_monetary_v: int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
# $ rfm_cell       : int  355 355 355 355 355 355 355 355 355 355 ...
# $ rfm_score      : num  4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 ...

# View the range of values first
table( df$rfm_score )
#   1.8   2.1   2.3   2.4   2.6   2.7   2.9     3   3.1   3.2   3.3 
# 32764 17649 10107  1633 23781   371  7725   198 11670  4251   177 
#  3.4   3.5   3.6   3.7   3.8   3.9     4   4.1   4.2   4.3   4.4 
# 8360  3051   256  6108  2537   724  5614  2484  4580  5621  4002 
#  4.6 
# 4048 

# create quantiles based on 
# interested probabilities
# from df$rfm_score
interested.quantiles <-
  quantile( x = df$rfm_score
            , probs = c( 0.9992, 0.8492, 0.5992, 0.2992, 0.1592 )
  )

# view vector
interested.quantiles
# 99.92% 84.92% 59.92% 29.92% 15.92% 
#    4.6    4.0    3.1    2.1    1.8 


# Assign labels based on each
# row's df$rfm_score
df$Label <-
  sapply( X = df$rfm_score
          , FUN = function( i )
            if( i >= interested.quantiles[ 1 ] ){

              return( "A" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 1 ] &&
                       i >= interested.quantiles[ 2 ] ){

              return( "B" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 2 ] &&
                       i >= interested.quantiles[ 3 ] ){

              return( "C" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 3 ] &&
                       i >= interested.quantiles[ 4 ] ){

              return( "D" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 4 ] &&
                       i >= interested.quantiles[ 5 ] ){

              return( "E" )

            } else if( i < interested.quantiles[ 5 ] ){

              return( "F")
            }
  )

# view the results
table( df$Label, useNA = "ifany" )
#    A     B     C     D     E 
# 4048 22301 37134 61464 32764 

# Wait..why aren't there any F values?
length( which( df$rfm_score < interested.quantiles[ 5 ] ) ) # [1] 0

# no "F" values are given because the
# there are not any values less than
# the 5th element in interested.quantiles

# end of script #
```

Comment: Appears great but i try it on a dataset [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/3n6c5e6q2wdemmn/stackoverfl) and i have problems. can you check it? Also two of the percentiles had a typo check them too on the question i have them corrected with bold, for correction in the new dataset please. Thank you very much

Comment: @J_p I updated the answer to reflect your desired probabilities. Can you explain what you mean by problems (i.e. if an error is occurring, please share where and the message you're receiving)? I did test with your data (just over 150k rows, using the `rfm_score` column) and no errors occurred. I'll leave the reproducible example data up for now since I couldn't find any problems.

Comment: The problem is that it gives no 'F'  category in my dataset  because the lowest value falls in the 'E' category according to the percentiles the exercise asks.Well maybe there is indeed no 'F' but since it is there i am not sure if it is correct not to use it.When you tried it, it worked with the 'F'?

Comment: @J_p, I updated my answer to include your data set. The reason you aren't seeing 'F' is because there are no values less than the 15.92th percentile. If you want 'F' to include values that are equal or less than the 15.92th percentile, you'll have to re-edit the question to more closely define the groups since they all rely on knowing who to include or exclude based on the inequalities of interest.

Comment: That's what i found too

Answer (score 0):

Q:

> A for the top 0.8% of the column
>   B for next 15% of the column
>   C for next 25% of the column
>   D for next 30% of the column
>   E for next 14% of the column
>   F for rest of the column

cuts at:

```
cuts <- c(1, 1 - cumsum( c(0.008, .15 ,.25,.30,.14)), 0)
cuts
[1] 1.000 0.992 0.842 0.592 0.292 0.152 0.000
```

Need to reverse order of lettering:

```
cut(dfrm$Grades, breaks= quantile(dfrm$Grades, cuts) ,include.lowest=TRUE, labels=LETTERS[6:1])
 [1] E D F D C C D F E C D D B B F A C
Levels: F E D C B A
```

Comment: 2.5% of your students have values at the highest level and you are trying to give only 0.8% of them A's. Did you actually mean 8% should get A's?

Comment: this is good observation but that is what the exercise asks. Also i tried with the unique function but gives only two values.What do you suggest?

Comment: I think the question is poorly posed. Good luck.